# php $_GET not working with clean urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I have the following .htaccess

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+edit-rsps\.php\?server=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ edit-rsps/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^edit-rsps/([^/]+)/?$ edit-rsps.php?server=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now when I try to output $_GET['server'] I get an empty result. I'm really new with php so any help is appreciated...

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser to test?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this row:

```
RewriteRule ^ edit-rsps/%1? [R=301,L]
```

---

edit:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^edit-rsps/([^/]+)/$ edit-rsps.php?server=$1 [L]
```

your url should look like

```
/edit-rsps/server-var/
```

Comment: I made the changes, edit-rsps.php?server=10 no longer redirects to edit-rsps/10, I can manually go to edit-rsps/10 but its messing my page up, and $_GET still does not work

Comment: If you want clean urls try edit-rsps/10/ it should be doing the same as edit-rsps.php?server=10

Comment: Clean URLs already have been working. I'm not able to use $_GET to get the variable.

Comment: try if edit-rsps/10/ outputs the var with code in my answer, if not post your php code